# Can I do array-way-slicing like array-way-indexing in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

how can I do array-way-slicing? 
I want to get the item `2,3; 7,8` in array `a` given the `start_idx` and `end_idx`. I tried `a[[0,1], start_idx: end_idx]` but failed.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]])
start_idx=[1,2]
end_idx=[3,4]
a[[0,1], start_idx: end_idx]] <- failed
[a[0,1:3], a[1,2:4]] #[array([2, 3]), array([7, 8])] <- wanted result
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your definition of `a`. End it with `)`. `[a[0,1:3], a[1,2:4]]` works fine then. Else, you can use a list comprehension

Comment: Thanks @Bazingaa, I updated.

Comment: will the row slices always ve the same length?

Comment: @hpaulj, they could be different. And the `len(start_idx)` is a bit large.

Comment: Then the result has to be a list, and the process an iteration over rows.

Comment: @hpaulj I forgot to mention, I would like to transform the numpy into `torch/pytorch` running at gpu if it could be done without looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
result = [a[i, start_idx[i]:end_idx[i]] for i in range(len(start_idx))]
print (result)
```

**Output**

```
[array([2, 3]), array([7, 8])]
```

Comment: First, make sure you understand why this loop works and your failed approach doesn't.

Comment: @hpaulj: I thought it's clear why the failed approach doesn't work. The slice indices are expected to be integers and not as lists.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was directed at the OP.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension with `enumerate` and `zip`:

```
res = [a[idx, start: end] for idx, (start, end) in enumerate(zip(start_idx, end_idx))]

# [array([2, 3]), array([7, 8])]
```

This is similar to @Bazingaa's solution, but iterates over `start_idx` / `end_idx` directly rather than positional list indexing.

The performance benefit is marginal and may only become apparent for large arrays. However, you may find the enumerating logic more readable.

```
n = 100000
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]*n)
start_idx = [1,2] * n
end_idx = [3,4] * n

def indexing(a, start_idx, end_idx):
    return [a[i, start_idx[i]:end_idx[i]] for i in range(len(start_idx))]

def enumerating(a, start_idx, end_idx):
    return [a[idx, start: end] for idx, (start, end) in enumerate(zip(start_idx, end_idx))]

%timeit indexing(a, start_idx, end_idx)     # 140 ms
%timeit enumerating(a, start_idx, end_idx)  # 124 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative answer. Just curious to know if there is any speed up involved with either of these?

Comment: @Bazingaa, See update,  you may see a small benefit for larger arrays.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting even though the gain is small.

Comment: @Bazingaa, Yep. I mean here you aren't looking at vectorised operations since your array result may be jagged, hence may not fit in a regular NumPy array. Just use the logic which is clearer to you.

Comment: I up vote your answer as it taught me something equally good.